# Is there any way to detect that an image url is not pointing to a non existent path using Django?

Tags: python, django, nginx

I have a website that sometimes points to images either locally or externally which do not exist.  When displayed in the template they simply show no photo which looks bad. It would be ideal to completely hide the object in question if the image src is invalid.

Does anybody know how to accomplish this with Django.  Or is there a better option out there?

Comment: You need javascript look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1641049/hiding-images-that-failed-to-load or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3235913/how-to-silently-hide-image-not-found-icon-when-src-source-image-is-not-found

Comment: hide it with javascript onerror function

Comment: sweet thank you guys, if somebody wants to answer I'll accept it.